# Are there any new ruby on rails versus django articles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django

I'm trying to decide between the two.  I don't know ruby or python very well.  I found some articles on SO.  Are there any recommended sites?  Googling only shows one or two.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I found a few.](http://www.google.com/search?q=rails+vs+django&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)  Most (if not all) of the articles linked on the first page of the results ought to be enough information to help you make an informed decision.